# 2 codes together with vba ? for each statement too big

Tags: vba, range, union, invoice

I need to to complete a task for my work. I am new to VBA-Excel so I am kind of stuck. This is also my first post so i am sorry in advance.

As you can see, this is a code I made so that i can get my invoices from a list. There are still some things missing like formatting all of it. But for me the most important part is to combine another worksheet with this code like the same exact code. I need a loop that does me 1st this code and then the second code which is similar.

Something like:

For each ID that is the same of the 2 lists do me a pdf file with all the invoices and all the sums.

The problem is that i get lost in all the coding because i have the feeling my for each statement is getting like 3 pages long which cannot be correct i assume.

My code as is:

```
Sub Schleife()

    Dim Zeile As Long
    Dim ZeileMax As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim m As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim strSpalte As String
    Dim strSpalte1 As String
    Dim strBereich As String
    Dim L As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim AR As Range
    Dim Le As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arrBlätter() As String
    Dim leereZelle As Long
    Dim strSpalte2 As String
    Dim strSpalte3 As String
    Dim strBereich2 As String


    'Worksheets
    Dim dl As Worksheet: Set dl = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DatenLadevorgänge")
    Dim lv As Worksheet: Set lv = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Ladevorgänge")
    Dim üb As Worksheet: Set üb = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Übersicht")
    Dim de As Worksheet: Set de = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DatenERoaming")
    Dim ge As Worksheet: Set ge = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Geräte")
    Dim ch As Worksheet: Set ch = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chips")
    Dim eR As Worksheet: Set eR = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("eRoaming")
    Dim mv As Worksheet: Set mv = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MEC-Verträge")
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    leereZelle = Columns(11).Find(What:="", Lookat:=xlWhole, Searchdirection:=xlNext).Row

    With Tabelle1
        If .Cells(leereZelle, 11) = "" Then üb.Cells(1, 1).Value = mv.Cells(leereZelle, 1).Value
    End With

    lv.Select
    lv.Range("A10:O100000").ClearContents
    üb.Range("A53:M100000").ClearContents

    With dl

        ZeileMax = .UsedRange.Rows.Count         'Fkt zur Aufuschung aller SmartCables'
        n = 10

        For Zeile = 2 To ZeileMax

            If .Cells(Zeile, 13).Value = lv.Range("A1").Value Then
                .Range(dl.Cells(Zeile, 2), dl.Cells(Zeile, 12)).Copy _
                Destination:=lv.Range(lv.Cells(n, 2), lv.Cells(n, 12))
                n = n + 1
            End If

        Next Zeile

        lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        'Sortieren
        .Range("B10:L" & lastrow).Sort Key1:=.Range("B10:B" & lastrow), _
                                       Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=.Range("C10:C" & lastrow), Order2:=xlAscending

        dl.Range("B10", dl.Range(dl.Cells(10, 2), dl.Cells(n, 13))).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo

    End With


    L = Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Row
    strBereich = "A10:O" & L
    strSpalte = "B"
    strSpalte1 = "O"

    If Range("B10") = "" Then
        Cells(10, 2).Value = "Keine Ladevorgänge vorhanden"
    Else
        lv.Range(strBereich).Sort _
        Key1:=Range(strSpalte & "1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range(strSpalte1 & "1"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                                                                       Header:=xlNo
        lv.Range("I" & L + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("I10:I" & L))
        lv.Range("J" & L + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("J10:J" & L))
        lv.Range("K" & L + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("K10:K" & L))
        lv.Range("L" & L + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("L10:L" & L))
        lv.Range("B" & L + 1).Value = "Gesamtsumme"
    End If

    lv.Range("C1").Value = "$B$2:$L$" & L + 1

    üb.Select

    With ge

        ZeileMax = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        n = 66

        For Zeile = 2 To ZeileMax
            If ge.Cells(Zeile, 1).Value = üb.Cells(1, 1) Then
                .Rows(Zeile).Copy Destination:=üb.Rows(n)
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next Zeile

    End With

    R = Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Row
    strBereich = "A53:M" & R
    strSpalte = "B"
    üb.Range(strBereich).Sort Key1:=Range(strSpalte & "1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

    mv.Select

    With mv
        .Cells(leereZelle, 11).Value = "ja"
        üb.Cells(36, 10).Value = .Cells(leereZelle, 10).Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question. You need to make you question concise and easy to understand. Please remove unnecessary code and explain clearly what you are trying to achieve. Commenting codes would also help the reader understand it better.

Comment: Also, put Option Explicit at the top, you have lots of undeclared and unassigned variables, alot of implicit references to activeworksheet and also comparisons for empty string literals that could be VBNullString comparisons.